# Is it possible to scan for Bluetooth "id's" using the iPhone gamekit API's

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Ok, before I get a ton of responses. I know you cannot talk to other Bluetooth devices (exchanging data or otherwise). I was just wondering if the Bluetooth id's appear when you use the Peer Picker as I'm currently investigating just the ability to detect other Bluetooth devices not the actual pairing.

Think of it like Bluetooth RFID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Bluetooth endpoint is published through Bonjour (usually the case) you can scan for it through standard Bonjour mechanisms, but AFAIK you can't scan for raw Bluetooth IDs. The peer picker hides all that even more and limits the scan to devices that publish with the same application service ID (so you only see others around you that are running the same app).

Comment: Thanks Ramin, that sucks :(. Oh well maybe it will come in due time.